# How to add Angular Bootstrap to yeoman

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, yeoman

I have an app in Yeoman, and I need to add bootstrap 3 in sass to it. 
I am using yeoman with Angular, Ecmascript 6.

Answer (score -1):

you can use generator-bootstrap:

Install: npm install -g generator-bootstrap

Usage: yo bootstrap

source: 
https://github.com/yeoman/generator-bootstrap